# How to skip an input and make an error code?

Tags: python, input

I'm very very veryy new to python and coding in general. I'm still learning the very basics, but I'm also trying to just play around and try out different things in python. I have tried making a very basic calculator that can +, -, *, /, take a number to the power of another number, and take the square root of 1 number.
Only thing I don't know how to do is skip the third input with num2, when I put in operator "sqrt" so I only take the sqrt of num1. Also I want to tell the user that if they put in an input for num1 that is less than 0 then they get an error.

Idk if I need to learn more to do something like this? I haven't learned about loops yet so I'm still very very new. Hope I can get some helps

```
#Making a basic calculator
from math import*
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
op = input("Enter operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "^":
    print(pow(num1,num2))
elif op == "sqrt":
    print(sqrt(num1))
elif op == "sqrt" and num1 <= 0:
    print("You cannot take the square root of numbers smaller than 0")
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is check what `op` is and only ask for `num2` if you need it:

```
op = input("Enter operator: ")
if op != "sqrt":
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
```